# How to make a Status Bar Application catch 'applicationDidResignActive:' with other Status Bar Apps?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsapplication

Right now I'm developing a Status Bar Application and I need to know when the app loses focus, every time. So I am currently using `applicationDidResignActive:` for that but that's not catching when I open another Status Bar App's menu.
How can I make `applicationDidResignActive:` (or any other method) catch every time my app loses focus, even when opening another Status Bar App?

Comment: would it help if you you are listening to NSApplicationNotifications (willHide/Unhide instead of resignActive) ?https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000012-BAJDHBID (ps: I haven't done any Mac OS programming, but on iOS, i have found UIApplicationNotificaitions are much more helpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're actually looking for is when the window looses focus.

You can use the following `NSWindowDelegate` method:

```
windowDidResignMain:
```

You also have to set `canBecomeMainWindow` to `YES`

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow {
    return YES;
}
```

Make sure to connect it to the delegate and you should be fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've done that and it's not working. I don't get any notification when I open another status bar app's menu

Comment: Have you connected the delegate?

Comment: And you have subclassed the window, setting `canBecomeMainWindow` to `YES`?

Comment: yes, I have the `canBecomeMainWindow` method in my NSWindow subclass and I'm setting it to `YES`.

Comment: I figured out that my NSWindow must have a title bar for that method to work. But I need it without title bar. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Why a title bar? The window in the example does not have a title bar

Comment: well, i've tried and it only works if the title bar is displayed. otherwise it won't work

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting the main window correctly? If you click on your status bar, you should set the window to be the main window. It works in the example project above, right?

Comment: forget about it, it's working now and to be honest I don't know why it's working now xD but never mind, thanks!

Comment: @PedroVieira Standard programming issue :D Thanks